# New Installed Drupal 8 Module Cannot Be Uninstalled

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have a fresh Drupal 8.2.5 installation and I just installed the "Contact Storage Module"

**MODULE INSTALLED:** https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage

The issue is that when I installed the new module **which DOES NOT comes originally with the Drupal installation**, the square to enable it is greyed out since the beginning.

**SEE GREYED OUT ON THIS IMAGE:** http://lposselt.com/1.png

[image]

And because of that I cannot UNINSTALL it too.

So the Module was installed successfully but I cannot enable or uninstall.

**NOTE:** I have installed other modules in this NEW Drupal Installation and every module works, this is the only module that gives me troubles.

**Does anyone knows how I can fix this?**

I will like to at least uninstall it.

---

**UPDATE:**

To make it work I checked the dependencies need it for the module.

**1.** Click on the description of the module.

**2.** You will see a drop down text with Required modules.

**3.** In my case I needed TOKEN MODULE

**4.** After installing it, the check box from CONTACT STORAGE was available to click and install

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you miss some dependencies for this module.

if you click on the arrow to collapse the module information, is there any module for required?

if yes, check that all of them are installed.

**edit:
Requires: Contact User System Views Filter Options Field Text Token**

i tested it myself and you need to have all of them installed AND activated.

Comment: yes, thanks, module worked after dependencies were installed. I had to install TOKEN MODULE in my case

Comment: @lupoll88 glad that i could helped you. accept that others can see where the right solution is.